# Dropping a connection upon a certain event

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, connection, internet-connection

Is it possible to drop connections to a number of remote stations when another is open? For example say we have a set of machines with the network addresses (IPs) `{A, B, C}` and another with the addresses `{D, E}`. Suppose we are connected to A, B and C and then connect to D and/or E.

How is it possible to drop all connections to A, B and C when connecting to D and/or E so that only the later remain active?

Comment: What does it mean to `drop a connection`? If you do not want to send anything to them, do not send anything to them.

Comment: Close all connections to hosts A, B and C when connected to D or E